# Book series about a boy who has a scroll in a graveyard and accidentally summons a sort of dragon thing

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember reading a series years ago that was really quite good.

A boy has a scroll in a graveyard and accidentally summons a sort of dragon thing, after a bit he goes to a school to learn to control his familiar. Other kids are learning to summon as well, mainly a small bug, they end up in a war with I think orcs or some such. He ends up coming home and inherited his family home and farm then another war or battle happens.It was a series I believe, in English, years being atleast a decade, was something about multiple races like elves and orcs and men, I do remember that I think he named his little dragon ignius or something similar, in the second book it went into a volcano and grew, then third it's big enough to ride, they summon the familiars from a kind of other plane of existence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to be a series called *Summoner*, the first book is titled *[The Novice](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/22297138-the-novice)*, and is written by Taran Matharu.

> As the pieces on the board maneuver for supremacy, Fletcher must decide where his loyalties lie. The fate of an empire is in his hands. The Novice is the first in a trilogy about Fletcher, his demon Ignatius, and the war against the Orcs.

Comment: Do you have the link to where you got the quote from you can [edit] in?

Comment: Thank you warcupine, that's exactly what it is, been bugging me for over a year now thanks alot.